# Svelte - ReferenceError: buffer is not defined

Tags: webrtc, svelte

Trying to setup a WebRtc connection in my new Svelte app, and am hitting this error whenever I try to import a library.

> ReferenceError: buffer is not defined

**Example Code:** https://github.com/nickgrealy/svelte-webrtc (link also below)

Here are the steps to reproduce: install the library, then import it on a `*.svelte` component.

e.g. [peerjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/peerjs)

```
npm i peerjs
import Peer from "peerjs";
```

also occurs for this library - [simple-peer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-peer)

```
npm i simple-peer
import Peer from "simple-peer";
```

Both give the following error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: buffer is not defined
    at main.ts:14
```

Not really sure what to try next... writing vanilla Javascript? Try other libraries?

I don't know how to configure rollup... (hoping it's something simple that one of you have come across before!).

N.B. not sure if relevant, I converted the Svelte project to Typescript (using the inbuilt script).

### ** Added code to reproduce **

https://github.com/nickgrealy/svelte-webrtc/blob/main/src/main.ts#L2

Console logs from `yarn dev`

```
yarn run v1.22.10
$ rollup -c -w
rollup v2.56.3
bundles src/main.ts → public/build/bundle.js...
(!) Missing shims for Node.js built-ins
Creating a browser bundle that depends on "buffer" and "events". You might need to include https://github.com/snowpackjs/rollup-plugin-polyfill-node
LiveReload enabled
(!) Plugin node-resolve: preferring built-in module 'buffer' over local alternative at '/Users/userx/svelte-webrtc/node_modules/buffer/index.js', pass 'preferBuiltins: false' to disable this behavior or 'preferBuiltins: true' to disable this warning
(!) Circular dependencies
node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js
node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js
node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_writable.js -> /Users/userx/svelte-webrtc/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js?commonjs-proxy -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js
node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_duplex.js -> /Users/userx/svelte-webrtc/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js?commonjs-proxy -> node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js
(!) Missing global variable names
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
buffer (guessing 'buffer')
events (guessing 'require$$0$1')
created public/build/bundle.js in 2.9s

[2021-09-05 00:31:10] waiting for changes...

> svelte-app@1.0.0 start
> sirv public --no-clear "--dev"


  Your application is ready~! 

  - Local:      http://localhost:5000
  - Network:    Add `--host` to expose

────────────────── LOGS ──────────────────

  [00:31:18] 200 ─ 5.50ms ─ /
  [00:31:18] 200 ─ 0.60ms ─ /global.css
  [00:31:18] 200 ─ 0.71ms ─ /build/bundle.css
  [00:31:18] 200 ─ 1.35ms ─ /build/bundle.js
  [00:31:22] 200 ─ 0.76ms ─ /global.css
  [00:31:22] 200 ─ 1.83ms ─ /build/bundle.css
  [00:31:22] 200 ─ 3.96ms ─ /build/bundle.js.map
```

### ** Update **

Added the [node plugin](https://github.com/nickgrealy/svelte-webrtc/commit/fec2d1fefc601d5ef70b6c68f9f0f7fb0c20b592), now getting this error...

> Uncaught ReferenceError: require$$1$1 is not defined

... with these logs.

```
yarn run v1.22.4
$ rollup -c -w
rollup v2.56.3
bundles src/main.ts → public/build/bundle.js...
(!) Missing shims for Node.js built-ins
Creating a browser bundle that depends on "buffer". You might need to include https://github.com/snowpackjs/rollup-plugin-polyfill-node
LiveReload enabled
(!) Circular dependency
polyfill-node.global.js -> polyfill-node.global.js
(!) Missing global variable name
Use output.globals to specify browser global variable names corresponding to external modules
buffer (guessing 'require$$1$1')
created public/build/bundle.js in 2.6s

[2021-09-05 00:57:04] waiting for changes...
npm WARN lifecycle The node binary used for scripts is /var/folders/05/qnr367194ss7ktgg_c2r57440000gp/T/yarn--1630767421122-0.4620373266212361/node but npm is using /Users/userx/.nvm/versions/node/v14.17.3/bin/node itself. Use the `--scripts-prepend-node-path` option to include the path for the node binary npm was executed with.

> svelte-app@1.0.0 start /Users/userx/svelte-webrtc
> sirv public --no-clear "--dev"


  Your application is ready~!
```

Comment: Sharing `main.ts` and full error stack may be helpful

Comment: Thanks @AllanChain - have added the logs and sample code... will try including rollup-plugin-polyfill-node / `preferBuiltins: false` / setting up globals... but have to work out how do that first.

Comment: Try install buffer package from npm: https://www.npmjs.com/package/buffer

Comment: @NickGrealy also add you `rollup.config.js` in your question with project structure.

Comment: Hi @Chandan - it's all in the public project I shared (to reproduce). Please check it out https://github.com/nickgrealy/svelte-webrtc

Comment: @NickGrealy setup [`browserify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-browserify-transform) in `rollup.config.js` which is the requirement for [`simple-peer`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-peer) if you are working in browser.

Comment: I'm not sure how to config rollup for your case. However, for this specific package `simple-peer`, the problem can be solve by using the pre-build dist `import Peer from "simple-peer/simplepeer.min.js";`

Comment: @Chandan - stuck now on `ReferenceError: navigator is not defined` (https://github.com/nickgrealy/svelte-webrtc/tree/chandan)

Comment: @NickGrealy reorder these plugins in `rollup.config.js` as nodePolyfills, commonjs then resolve

Comment: @NickGrealy for `peerjs` there is no need for [`browserify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-browserify-transform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`peerjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/peerjs) [`browserify`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-browserify-transform) is not required and change output `format` to `cjs` in `rollup.config.js`.

If you want to keep `iife` then you need to disable `strict` mode in `rollup.config.js` under output property `strict: false` because the library has some issue.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Would be good to know why `cjs` works. Also started getting this error "module is not defined at main.ts:8" - any idea why?

Comment: @NickGrealy I am not getting any error should I include `rollup.config.js` and I not sure but the problem maybe because of the libraries are in mixed formats.